# Why Does ```__file__``` Directory Keep Going to AppData?

Tags: python, path, operating-system, pyinstaller, filepath

I'm working on a large project and am nearly done so I thought of installing pyinstaller so that I can convert the python script to an .exe file.

When I ran the .exe file, there was an error "Unhandled Exception.." basically saying that one of the directories I placed in the script to a file doesn't exist. The directory is:
`'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI45202\\Images\\SaveChangesButton.png'`

This shouldn't be the directory though. Here is an alternative script that has the same problem (it's shorter):

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

filepathforpythonfile = __file__
filepathforpythonfile = filepathforpythonfile.replace("Understanding OSModule.py", "")
filepathforpythonfile = filepathforpythonfile + "/Images/SaveChangesButton.png"
__file__ = os.path.abspath(filepathforpythonfile)
im = Image.open(__file__)
im.show()
```

It works perfectly fine. In fact if I run in the IDE `print(__file__)`, the file directory of the image comes out perfectly.

When I use pyinstaller to convert the top to a .exe file, I get an error by the OS not the IDE. The directory comes out to \AppData\Local or something random I don't know.

Now, I must say my knowledge of paths and directory and the os module is very limited so bear with my ignorance. Many thanks in advance.

NOTE: Here "Understanding OSModule.py" is the name of the .py file. The image folder sits in the same folder as the .py file.

Comment: Why did you put the `tkinter` tag? Also doesn't `__file__` become a string that ends in `.exe`? I have no idea how `pyinstaller` works so it's just a guess.

Comment: @TheLizzard Oh thankyou. I removed the tkinter tag.

Comment: If you are using `--onefile` mode, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/14278613) :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you still have the problem since it's been 2 years since you asked the question, but I'll answer it because I'm sure there are still people facing the same problem.

The thing is, when you create an .exe file with PyInstaller and run it, it executes in the \AppData\Local\Temp... directory, so the program thinks that the required files are in that folder.

One solution would be this:

```
exe_path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
exe_dir = os.path.dirname(exe_path)
im = Image.open(exe_dir)
```